# Как грепать по 2 параметрам(например по времени и коду ошибки)

Tags: grep

Часто спрашивают вопрос в личку как загрепать логи по дате и коду ошибки.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `ack` https://habr.com/ru/post/502734/

Comment: оформите, пожалуйста, как отдельные вопрос и ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep "[45]00"  logs/2020/01/apache_2020-01-10.txt logs/2020/01/apache_2020-01-15.txt | grep "12:33:"
```

Поиск в 2 файлах 400 и 500 ошибки в нужное время.
Если нужно вывести ошибки в другой файл то можно так.
где "w" - проверит слово в точности, а не его вхождение.

```
$ grep -i -w "500" test.txt > bug/event/500.txt
```

---

PS Если у вас есть варианты лучше напишите тоже.